# Creating axis gap in histograms

Tags: r, histogram, axis-labels

I'm trying to create a gap in a histogram between 0.6 and 1 (on the y axis) but don't really know how to go about this. The gap.barplot solution does not seem to work and i'd love to keep the aesthetic of the plots consistent with the other ones. Ideally it would look something like this: [image]

The general plot code attempt looks like this:

```
 h <- hist(benthosBx$length_mm, breaks = seq(0, 10, 0.5),  plot = FALSE)
h$counts <- h$counts / nrow(benthosBx)
gap.plot(h, xlab = 'Body length (mm)', ylab = '', gap = c(0.4,0.8),ylim = c(0,0.6), xlim = c(0,10), main = ' ', xaxt='n', yaxt='n', col = "grey")
axis(side=1, at=seq(0,10, 1))
axis(side=2, at=seq(0,1, 0.1))
```

dput of the data:

```
structure(list(lakeID = c("WE2", "WE2"), length_mm = c(1.52172197930582, 
1.63884515191493), date = structure(c(1592352000, 1597881600), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), year = c(2020L, 2020L)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Could you share some of `benthosBx` data frame so that other users can reproduce your results?

Answer (score 0):

Set the value to zero.

```
plot(h, ylim = c(0,0.6), xlim = c(0,10), col = 8)
```

[image]

```
h$counts[h$breaks == 1] <- 0  ## set to zero
plot(h, ylim = c(0,0.6), xlim = c(0,10), col = 8)
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)
h <- hist(runif(100, 0, 10), breaks = seq(0, 10, 0.5), plot = FALSE)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening with this code or how to make a gap from it. Is there a gap on the x axis?